# Excel Macro to average data between data value changes

Tags: excel, vba

i have two columns: data and results. every so often the values in results change to 10 and I need to find the average, min and max during, before and after each time of the corresponding cells in data. So average value in column data over the course of 10s, and the space between 10s. Sort of like finding the average at a local peak (or plateau in this case) and the space between peaks.  Then spit these out into another table that says what the average is and if it is before during or after a 10 occurrence. How do i designate this if statement to cover these cases and indicate what average corresponds to what section of data?

```html
0.5    10
0.8    10
1.1    10
1.4    10
1.7    10
2    10
2.3    5
2.6    5
2.9    5
3.2    5
3.5    10
3.8    10
4.1    10
4.4    10
4.7    10
5    10
5.3    10
5.6    10
5.9    5
6.2    5
6.5    5
6.8    5
7.1    10
7.4    10
7.7    10
8    10
8.3    10
8.6    10
8.9    10
9.2    10
9.5    10
9.8    10
10.1    10
10.4    5
10.7    5
11    5
```

Comment: add some data sample and expected result

Comment: how do i attach a file?

Comment: Or a table can i add that?

Comment: thanks for just voting me down guys :/

Comment: Edit your question, copy&paste a little data sample (not all file), give it some format

Comment: do you need real working code or can I just give you some direction? I don't have the time right now for a full answer

Comment: Some direction would be great, working code obviously better.  I just don't see how I can word these averageIf statements so that they stop when there is a data value change. I've been trying like if cell is < 10 start over but it isnt working.

Comment: nevermind wrong comment spot

Comment: I dont understand what you need to see. the answer below this though is doing what I need to i think.

Comment: OK that's great. Perhaps you would mark as answer, have go at coding the SubTotal command in your VBA and post again with a new question if you need further help with that.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to make use of the built-in Excel SubTotal command and apply multiple functions using this.  See [this link](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2011/11/17/multiple-excel-subtotals/) for the concept and the image below for the sort of basic output.  You can code this in VBA and format the resulting output to suit.

Note that if you use this method you will need column headers for the SubTotal command.

[image: Partial specimen output]

Comment: I dont think that what you posted below is what I am talking about. I want the average/min/max of the other column over the range where the change column is 10 and the same for between ranges of 10.

Comment: Then sorry, but I am still not clear of your requirement. As @Horaciux has requested perhaps you would post a formatted specimen of what your your expected output should look like, alongside your two columns of data.

Comment: I've just re-read your comment.  Please look again - I think I have provided the average/max/min of the 'Change' groups (of 10 and 5), in the 'Result' column itself, on the same row as the Max, Min, Average labels.

Comment: I will try and get a formatted one up, it would be so much easier if i could input a file!

Comment: I looked at your table and it is calculating what I need, but the link you provided would mean I have to chrun through my 50files by hand to do that method which i cant do since they have 600000 rows or more and i have no idea where the changes occur. Is there a way to make this a script?

Comment: As per my answer, you can code the SubTotal command in VBA.  The link was just to illustrate that you can use SubTotal to summarise multiple functions.  A specimen output, even if you illustrate it manually, would still be helpful.